# application/json served from API to frontend save PDF with correct number of pages but no content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

After a request to an API, I get a PDF as a response. I then pass this response to the frontend for the user to print, however on the frontend I only manage to get a PDF with the correct number of page, but all the pages are blank.

Here is the request:

```
const streamResponse = await axios({
    url : endpoint_url,
    method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            some authorization parameters,
        },
        responseType: 'stream'
    });
        
    streamResponse.data.pipe(res)
```

On the frontend I have this code:

```
let blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'output.pdf';
link.click();
```

I also tried to use the file-saver library to directly save the PDF but I get the same result.
The data in the response is something like that :

```
"%PDF-1.4
%����
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 1379>>stream
x���]s�6����3�N�,���%���N����Nn,۴|8|$�_IX a�����$A���WGGΛv>�6�fs̀�#���%d�l����ٿ�ݐ�덦S�L@#&b=$K��>���y�dOd'Y�]��7EV�7X?�h�>`_�
�t%�=��,����!N3Pm,�Ɠ�{�tPYb`������P�jVڭJR����c5�ي��N�$� i�8�Oqlt����wg�#����$�-gC�%��&$Q���q�@���>� �W’�i��Ż+TM��s���&uÀk�x$(��|I)8�S^̑�M��y���Na���<)&���hq��D^�̏#HW�G�5~'�M� .......
```

I know that it is a valid PDF file because I am able to save it on the server, but I cannot find anyway to serve it to the client side.

I also tried to save it in the server and then using a request using the below code to serve it to the client:

```
let pdfFile = fs.createReadStream(pdfFilePath)
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
pdfFile.pipe(res);
```

Comment: @KJ thank you for reply. Saving the file to /public/ was also something I tried, but when using <a href="file.pdf" download>file.pdf</a>, chrome returns a "Failed - No File" in the download manager. It seems to be coming from the fact that it prefix the file URL with the base url of my app and I didn't find a way to prevent it from doing. Do you know if there is a way around that?

Comment: is it solved even i got struck with same problem bro

Comment: @ksk Yes it was solved. My solution was: use the fs library to create a write stream, using axios to make the request for the pdf with a responseType as 'stream', and then pipe the stream into the write stream. The file we got from the stream was send sent to the front end as any other data and it worked fine

Comment: I tried with the above-mentioned but still not working
do you have any repo or sample code for glance

Comment: @ksk I just edited my post with the code sample of what worked for me. Hopefully it'll work for you too

Comment: "EDIT: what worked for me:" - is this an actual answer here? If so, you are fully encouraged to answer your own question with an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

```
    let outputFilePath = splitDirName + `client/public/manifests/${ filename }.pdf`;

    // Open fs writer to write the pdf
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream(outputFilePath);
        
    // Get the PDF as a stream
    const streamResponse = await axios({
        url: urlString,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {},
        responseType: 'stream'
    });

    // Pipe the response to the writer
    streamResponse.data.pipe(writer);

    // return the path at which the pdf was saved
    return outputFilePath;
```

The outputFilePath is then simply passed to the front-end, and the front end simply open the pdf file in a new tab with:

```
window.open(res.data.substring(urlIndex), '_blank');
```